# Installing local to live WP into subdirectory

Tags: database, mysql, directory, localhost, phpmyadmin

I am having a bit of trouble moving a local WP site live and into a subdirectory. I want a static homepage for now (index.html in the root folder) while I work on the live site (would be found in root/folder/, so website.com/subfolder/).

Following [these steps](http://pastebin.com/MMx7PRWv) I've had success installing WP into the root folder, but it doesn't work for a subdirectory. I was wondering if someone could walk me through how to get it to work, so I have a static homepage and am able to work on the WP site live. My host is dreamhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to test out your existing(local) site on the server; you have done the right thing as far as I can see on pastebin except for 1 thing

On step 10 - you replaced all occurances of "localhost" with your servername. Instead you should have replaced it with servername/directoryName.

If you still have issues, please let me know the exact issue you are facing and if possible the URL to your website on your host.

**EDIT**:
The issue that OP was facing was `unable to connect to database`. So the solution was to update DB details in the `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: @srihari- I actually did do that, but it didn't work

Comment: @vytfla So, when you access http://servername/directory what do you get? Browser's default 404 or Wordpress 404?

Comment: If I followed the steps above, I get an error when I try the search and replace script

Comment: Please share the error. Do you have Multisite activated? can you share the link. Later on you can have the directory password protected.

Comment: Error establishing database. I don't have multisite activated. I have no idea where to go from here, it's becoming frustrating.

Comment: Have you updated the database connection info in **wp-config.php**? Your host name at Dreamhost is either mysql.[yourdomain].com or mysql.[yoursubdomain].dreamhosters.com.

Comment: @vytfla In your root folder, not the one that has wordpress today, please put the following into a file named index.php. 
`<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("DBserverName","UserName","Password","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }else{echo ("Successfully Connected To DB");}
?>`

Please share the results you get after accessing this file from browser i.e. www.yourdomainname.com/index.php

Comment: @epilektric- Do I update the host when I change the user/pass/database? Because I haven't been changing the MYSQL hostname in the wp-config.php file manually at any point.

Comment: @vytfla Please update the host. The MYSQL server has been changed from the previous server address. Please update it to the new server where you created the new DB.

Comment: @srihari- So in the link I provided, when I get to #8 (wp-config.php), I also have to change localhost to whatever my MYSQL hostname is?

Comment: @vytfla That's correct.

Comment: @srihari- Thank you so much, that worked. Wasn't aware I had to do that, I didn't have it in my notes. I'm so relieved. Thank you for sticking by and helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a static HTML homepage you have a few options.

### Move the site out of the server root directory

Move the entire site into a sub-directory like "blog", "dev", etc.

Moving the site will require updating the database and all the other things that go along with [moving a site to a new domain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

### Leave the site at the server root directory

#### Option 1

Use an **htaccess** file to redirect based on IP.

You can create an HTML homepage and use your **htaccess** file to redirect anybody that does not have your IP address. Do not name the HTML page **index**, **home** or **default** because these may override **index.php**. In this example I use **homepage.html**.

Upload the file to the root directory where Wordpress is. Add the following code to your **.htaccess** file at the very top. Replace the IP address with your own ([what is my IP?](http://www.whatismyip.com/)), replace the domain name with your own, and change the page name if you didn't use **homepage.html**.

```
# BEGIN maintenance
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/homepage\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/homepage.html [R=307,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.000\.000\.000
</IfModule>
# END maintenance
```

#### Option 2

Use [a plugin to control maintenance mode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=maintenance%20mode).

I have used the one called Maintenance Mode without problems. If you are logged in you can see everything on the front-end and back-end of the site. If you are not logged in you get the maintenance page.

This is by far the easiest solution and will make launching the site a breeze when it's time to go public with it.